# Не известный отступ ни к чему не принадлежащий

Tags: html, css, joomla

столкнулся с такой проблемой, на моём сайте появился отступ в бок, из-за которого появился ненужный горизонтальный скролл. Я проверил не один элемент не вылазит за обозначенные рамки, а при просмотре исходного кода отступа, он ничего не показывает(его тупо нет). Подскажите пожалуйста как его убрать.[image: отступ]

Comment: Что-то должно быть. Проверьте инспектором элементов браузера.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

может оказаться элемент нулевой высоты.

задайте всем элементом границы для отладки `box-shadow:0 0 10px red inset;` и смотрите.

Answer (score 1):

В общем инспектор браузера переместил с правого края вниз и сразу нашёл этот подляный блок

Answer (score 0):

Проверьте все элементы спозиционированые свойством `position:`. При его использовании отступы могут вылазить за родительские элементы и создавать непонятный отступ.